# Solve apparent need for outside reference to entity inside aggregate (DDD)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to follow DDD principles to create a model for determining whether or not an Identity has access to an Action belonging to a Resource.

A Resource (e.g. a webservice) is something that holds a number of Actions (e.g. methods), which can be accessed or not. An Identity is something that wants to access one or more Actions on a Resource. For example, someone uses an api-key in a call to a webservice method, and it must be determined whether or not access is allowed.

As I currently see it, Identity and Resource are aggregate roots, and Action is an entity belonging to Resource. It doesn't seem to make sense for an Action to live on its own; it will always belong to one Resource. An Identity needs to know to which Resource Actions it has access. This seems to suggest the following model.

[image: Model]

However, as I understand it, this violates the principle that something outside an aggregate cannot reference an entity within the aggregate. It must go through the root. Then I'm thinking, what if Action was the aggregate root and Resource an entity? But that doesn't seem very logical to me. I've also been thinking of merging Resource and Action into one entity, which would then be an aggregate root, but that also seems wrong to me.

So it leaves me kind of stuck on how to model this correctly using DDD principles. Anyone have a good idea on how to model this?

**Update:** The model I'm trying to create is the identity model for defining which resource actions an Identity is allowed to access. It is not a model for the actual implementation of resources and actions.

**Update 2 - invariants:** 
Id of all objects is given at birth, is unique, and doesn't change. ApiKey of Identity must be unique across all Identities.
Name of Action must be unique within aggregate, but two different Resources can have Actions with same names, e.g. Resource "R1" can have an Action "A1" and Resource "R2" can also have an Action "A1", but the two "A1"s are not the same.

Comment: What are the properties / behaviour of Action that make it more than just a method call on a Resource? It sounds like you have SomeResource.SomeAction() and you could check the Identity has permissions to call the method in an application service

Comment: Also, how is a web service an AggregateRoot? Isn't it just a webservice?

Comment: I'm trying to model the identity model - the one that describes which Identities have access to which Resources and Actions. So Resource could represent a webservice, but is not the physical webservice.

Comment: Do identities have roles? Or are you modelling each individual identity as having access (or not) to many Actions on many Resources?

Comment: Also what invariants are you enforcing within your aggregates? What are the business rules around Identities, Resources and Actions? This knowledge is needed in order to advise on modelling these things

Comment: There are no roles. Regarding invariants I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query or Write Operation?

The domain model in terms of aggregates and entities has it's purpose in DDD in order to simplify expression and enforcement of the invariants - as write operations are applied to the model.

As mentioned in @VoiceOfUnreason's answer, the question 'Can this user do action A on resource R' is a question that doesn't necessarily need to flow through the domain model - it can be answered with a query against either a pre-projected read-only model, or standard SQL querying against the tables that make up the write model persistence (depend on your needs).

### Splitting Contexts to Simplify Invariants

However, your question, whilst mostly about how to identify if an identity is allowed to carry out an action, is implicitly seeking a simpler model for the updating of resources, actions and permissions.  So to explore that idea... there are implicitly two types of write operations:

1. Defining available resources and actions
2. Defining which resource action combinations a particular identity is permitted to carry out

It's possible that the model for these two types of operations might by simplified if they were split into different bounded contexts.

In the first, you'd model as you have done, an Aggregate with Resource as the aggregate root and Action as a contained entity.  This permits enforcing the invariant that the action name must be unique within a resource.

As changes are made in this context, you publish events e.g. `ActionAddedToResource`, `ActionRemovedFromResource`.

In the second context, you'd have three aggregates:

- Identity
- ResourceAction

  - Properties: Id, ResourceId, ResourceName, ActionId, ActionName
- Permission

ResourceAction instances would be updated based events published from the first context - created on ActionAddedToResource, removed on ActionRemovedFromResource.  If there is a resource with no actions, there is no ResourceAction at all.

Permission would contain two identity references - `IdentityId` and `ResourceActionId`

This way when carrying out the operation "Permit this user to do this action on this resource" the operation is just to create a new Permission instance - reducing the set of operations that affect the Identity aggregate's consistency boundary - assuming there are no invariants that require the concept of a 'permission' to be enforced within an Identity aggregate?

This also simplifies the query side of things, as you just need to search for a Permission entry with matching `identityId`, `resourceName` and `actionName` after joining `Permissions` to `ResourceActions`.

### Responsibility Layers

The DDD Book in the section on Strategic Design refers to organising your contexts according to responsibility layers.  To use the terms from the book, the above suggestion is based on the idea of a 'capability' responsibility layer (defining resources and actions) and an 'operational' responsibility layer (defining identity permissions and checking identity permissions).

Comment: Ok, I think I get where you are going. But can you clarify the ResourceAction a bit? Am I correct in assuming it will hold ResourceName and ActionName, as in copies of the names defined on Resource and Action? And these are to be updated using domain events?

Comment: Yep, that's right - it could also have ResourceId and ActionId so you can update the names if when the upstream resource and action names are modified - but does that happen often compared with defining identity access permissions?

Comment: I don't think it will happen often, but I wouldn't want to make it a limitation, so that name couldn't be changed. Anyway, storing the Action ID outside the aggregate where it lives, doesn't that violate a DDD principle regarding local IDs?

Comment: Updating the name would be possible, just you might have to update multiple `ResourceActions` in the Operational context for one name change in the Capability context.  That's the tradeoff with making fulfillment of the purpose of the Operational context (managing access permissions) much simpler.

Comment: Technically, storing a local id isn't forbidden - as long as it's only interpreted in the context of the aggregate root id, and the non-root entity is only accessed via the root.  Since we are also storing ResourceId, ActionId can be considered in conjunction with ResourceId.  But more accurately, in this new operational context, it's not a reference to an entity, it's just a ValueObject property on `ResourceAction` to help identify which `ResourceActions` need updating when handling an `ActionUpdatedEvent` (the event would include both ResourceId and ActionId as ActionId may not be unique).

Comment: All right, yeah, I follow your reasoning. This actually seems to solve my problem, although a bit more involved than what I initially thought necessary. But it makes it cleaner for the different contexts, and that's an important aspect. I mark this as the answer, but want to thank everyone for their input. It all helped me with a better understanding of DDD concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the invariants you mention, Identity can contain a Resources dictionary/map where resourceId is the key and the value is a set of unique action names/ids. This gives you uniqueness of action names for each resource per identity:

`Map<Resource, Set<Action>>`

Alternatively, you could have a set/list of Resources and they have a collection of Actions on them. Uniqueness can be enforced by the collection types available in the language you're coding in:

```
Set<Resource> Resources

class Resource {
    Set<Action> Actions
}
```

Even simpler, just create a Resource-Action key by combining the two ids and store it in a set or something to give you uniqueness:

`Resource1-Action1`

`Resource1-Action2`

`Resource2-Action1`

...etc

You can then have a method on Identity to add a new Resource-Action combination.

I don't see anything in your description to warrant Actions being Entities as they appear to have no identity of their own.

This is really simple though, so I am presuming you've simplified the domain considerably.

Comment: I guess your first suggestion with IDs in dictionary could be a way to do it, though referencing Action IDs outside the Resource<>-Action aggregate seems to be a violation. Using Action name instead of ID in the dictionary introduces complex update scenario, since Action names i both aggregates must be in sync.

Comment: I really think Identities and Resources+Actions are two different concepts. They can live independently of each other. E.g. there will be an administrative UI for managing Identities, and another for managing Resources+Actions.

Comment: It may be that Actions don't need to be entities, but I need a way to be able to give Identities access at the Action level. So I must realize that connection somehow - preferably without having to duplicate Action name.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, someone uses an api-key in a call to a webservice method, and it must be determined whether or not access is allowed.

That's a query.  Fundamentally, there's nothing wrong with answering a query by joining two read-only copies of entities that belong to different aggregates.

You do need to be aware that, because the aggregates can change independently of each other, and because they can change independently of your query, the answer you get when you do the join may be stale, and not entirely consistent.

For example, you may be joining a copy of an Identity written 100ms ago to a copy of an Action written 200ms ago.  Either of the aggregates could be changing while you are running the query.

Answer (score 0):

I will also expand on the bit identified by @VoiceOfUnreason:

> For example, someone uses an api-key in a call to a webservice method,
>   and it must be determined whether or not access is allowed.

How would the particular bit of exposed functionality know what security is applied to it?  The answer is provided by @Chris Simon: `Permission`.

I have a common implementation that I use that has not been distilled into an `Identity & Access` BC of its own but follows closely with what you are attempting --- I hope :)

A `Session` has a list of `Permission` strings.  Typically I use a `uri` to represent a permission since it is quite readable.  Something like `my-system:\\users\list`.   Anyway, *how* the user is assigned these permissions could be anything.  There may very well be a `Role` containing permissions and a user is assigned to one or more roles; or the user may even have a custom list of permissions.

When a `SessionToken` is requested (via authentication) the server retrieves the permissions for the relevant user and creates a session with the relevant permissions assigned to it.  This results in a read-side `token/permission`.

Each exposed bit of functionality (such as a rest endpoint) is assigned a permission.  In c# web-api it is simply an attribute on the method:

```
[RequiredPermission("my-system:\\order\create")]
```

My session token is passed in the header and a quick check determines whether the session has expired and whether the session (assigned to the user) has access to the resource.

Using your design the `Action` may very well carry the required `Permission`.  The `User` would still require a list of either roles or `UserAction` entries that contain, perhaps, the `ResourceId` and `ActionId`.  When the use logs in the read-optimized session structures are created using that structure.

If there is an arbitrary `Action` list that can be assigned to any `Resource` then both `Resource` and `Action` are probably aggregates.  Then you would need a `ResourceAction` as mentioned by @Chris Simon.  The `ResourceAction` would then contain the `Permission`.

That's my take on it...