# DDD suggest a relation between entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have a following structure.

`Resources` can have multiple `endpoints`.

Example:
Resource `tickets` can be accessed on following `endpoints`:

- /api/tickets
- /api/agent/tickets
- /api/group/5/tickets
- /api/tickets/closed  etc.

At first, this looks like aggregate, where `Resource` is AR, and `endpoints` are child entities.

I also have `UserTypes`. 
What I need is to build a relation between `Usertypes` and `Endpoints`, so each `UserType` can have a diferrent access for endpoints.
Example for, `UserType` admin could access all `endpoints` for tickets `resource`, while user type agent could have access to only portion of `endpoints` for the same `resource`.

What would be a suggested way to connect `EndPoints` and `UserTypes` in terms of DDD?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve apparent need for outside reference to entity inside aggregate (DDD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255123/solve-apparent-need-for-outside-reference-to-entity-inside-aggregate-ddd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need anything else other than a collection of mapping a between `Resources` and `Endpoints` on a `UserType`? This would give you all usertypes their unique resource endpoint access rights

Also seems to be the same question as [Solve apparent need for outside reference to entity inside aggregate (DDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39255123/2650743)

I would probably create something like the following:

```
class ResourceEndpoint {
    Guid resourceId;
    Guid endpointId;
}

class UserType {
    List<ResourceEndpoint> ThingsICanAccess;
}
```

Comment: Maybe i modeled this wrong. Maybe Endpoint should be separate AR. When adding an endpoint, We must select to which resource he belongs.

Comment: Does the adding of the endpoint to the resource also need to be in the same transaction as adding the resource-endpoint mapping to the usertype?

Comment: Alright, and where would you place UserTypeEndpoints? As a separate AR, As a list of value objects inside UserType, where each holds a reference to Endpoint?

Comment: "Does the adding of the endpoint to the resource also need to be in the same transaction as adding the resource-endpoint mapping to the usertype?" - No. You will be able to edit user type, and assign them existing endpoints later on.

Comment: What are they? if they are just a mapping from usertype to ResourceEndpoint (which sounds like a new object that is just the identifiers of a Resource and an Endpoint) then they would be a collection on the UserType.

Comment: why resourceID inside ResourceEndpointClass? All i needed was endpointID.

Comment: How do you know what resource the endpoint is related to? Is it on the Endpoint object already?

Comment: Endpoint is part of the resource. Resource can have multiple endpoints.